# Can't add circumflex or hat to pi symbol in latex text

Tags: symbols, amsmath, text

I'm writing a report and need to reference a 'pi hat' in text. From google and Stack questions i've seen, a good solution is `\^{\textpi}`. However this puts that hat left of the symbol for me (^x). Curiously using the circumflex on single letters is fine though, ie `\^{a}`. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: With `babel` you can do `\textgreek{\^p}`, but should this really be text or is this a math symbol?

Comment: `$\hat{\pi}$` could be an option.

Comment: Thank you, both helpful suggestions. I've used $\hat{\pi}$

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to the Greek font and use the corresponding hat accent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\newcommand{\pihat}{{\textgreekfont\^\textpi}}

\begin{document}

\^a\pihat x

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's not *really* the same shape, though. If you want the same glyph, you have to go the hard way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\pihat}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\^{}\cr\noalign{\vskip-1ex}\textpi\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\^a\pihat x

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An accent command (like `\^`) must be followed by the character to be accented, with only font assignments intervening. But the expansion of `\textpi` seems to be much more complex than that, so that when TeX finally "sees" the pi character, it cannot relate this to the accent command any more.

If you know the name of the font that contains the upright pi (say, `\textgreekfont`) and which character position is occupied by pi within that font (say, `p`), you could write `\^{\textgreekfont p}`.